# Greenshot: select and move parts of screenshot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, screenshot

How can I select and cut & paste (ie: move) areas of my screenshot ?

In MS Paint I would use `select` and then would drag my selected area around:

[image]

=========================================================

## In order to turn this:

[image]

=========================================================

## Into this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take the screenshot and then follow the instructions in SS, first select the crop button then select the area you want to cut and then click on the Check button on the left corner and you have cut the image you need.

[image]

As written below by arvik: Then UNDO the last step so you return to the uncropped full image, where you can now paste & move the cropped selection.
Cumbersome, but works.

Comment: thanks for your reply, although what I need to do is to cut only a selected small area of my screenshot and then paste it again into the same screenshot. I do not need to simply crop :)

Comment: Umm I think then open Screen shot in Greenshot editor and the crop the area you want select it then copy  it to clipboard, now undo all the steps and paste it where you want and edit the SS according to your chouce, or I'll say use a better image editor to do so as its not professional image editor just an editor to highlight the things. :)

Comment: Thanks again, but it won't work in Greenshot :)

Comment: I mean after select the area cut it and copy to clipboard and then undo the steps and paste it on the ss, I tried it and it did the job.

Comment: ok, although it won't cut, it *copies*

Answer (score 0):

What i do to make this work is take another screenshot of the picture in the greenshot app and select "copy to clipboard", i can then paste (ctrl-v) the area i selected for the screenshot.  At least this will copy the area you want so you can paste it.